# Profound UI ajax request to RPG

Tags: javascript, ajax, profound-grid

I am working with Profound UI and RPG. I need to submit ajax request onClick when checkbox is checked with 3 keys as parameters. I'm new to profound and can't figure out how to make this work.

from the profound docs:

```
var ajaxRequest = new pui.AjaxRequest({
  url: "getInfo.pgm",
  method: "post",
  async: true,
  suppressAlert: true,
  params: {
    customerName: "David Russo",
    customerNumber: "H52N-100"
  },
  onsuccess: infoHandler,
  onfail: failHandler
});
ajaxRequest.send();
```

When i try and use my program name for the url, the request goes to
http://ip:port/profoundui/programName .
I think when i get the request to hit my program I can figure out what to make my RPG program listen for to pick up the parms, i just need to know how to hit my program at this point.

My checkbox has onClick added from the designer screen with updateRecord(e); and my function in javascript is the code above wrapped in my js call.